# How to create custom filter in register_post_type list page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using register_post_type to create post_meta. So in its listing page by default it is showing date filter. I want remove all default filter and i want to create my new custom filter. My code to create post_type is -

```
//Manage news Feed
add_action('init', 'manage_news_feed');

function manage_news_feed() {
    register_post_type('news_feed', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Feed Management',
            'singular_name' => 'Feed Management',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Feed',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Feed',
            'new_item' => 'New Feed',
            'view' => 'View',
            'view_item' => 'View Feed',
            'search_items' => 'Search Feed',
            'not_found' => 'No Feed',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Feed found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent News Feed'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 100,
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array(''),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url('images/adv-.png', __FILE__),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
            )
    );
}
```

And this is to add custom column to in list page-

```
//Add custom column for feed_url
add_filter( 'manage_edit-news_feed_columns', 'news_feed_custom_columns', 25, 1 );
function news_feed_custom_columns( $cols )
{
    $cols = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "News Feed Url",
        "category_id" => "Category Id",
        "date" => "Created Date"
    );

    return $cols;
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'custom_columns', 2, 1 );
function custom_columns( $col )
{
    global $post;

    switch ( $col )
    {
        case "feed_url" :

            if( '' != get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'feed_url', true ) )
                echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'feed_url', true );
            else
                echo __( 'N/A', 'txt_domain' );

            break;

        case "category_id" :


                echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'category_id', true );


            break;

    }
}
```

my code for Custom_meta_box is -

```
// Add fields for news Feed

add_action('admin_init', 'my_admin');

function my_admin() {
    add_meta_box('movie_review_meta_box', 'Feed Details', 'news_feed_meta_box', 'news_feed', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}

//Function to create meta_box for news feed
function news_feed_meta_box($feed) {

    global $wpdb;
    $category_name = esc_html(get_post_meta($feed->ID, 'category_id', true));
    $feed_url = esc_html(get_post_meta($feed->ID, 'post_title', true));
    ?>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Category Name</td>
             <td><?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => 'category_id', 'hierarchical' => true));?></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Feed Url</td>
            <td><input id="post_title" type="text" required="" data-required="true" size="40" name="post_title" value="<?php echo $feed_url; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>  
    </table>
    <?php 
}

add_action('save_post', 'add_feed_fields', 10, 2);
function add_feed_fields($feed_id, $feed) {
    // Check post type for feed
    if ($feed->post_type == 'news_feed') {

        if (isset($_POST['category_id']) && $_POST['category_id'] != '') {            
            update_post_meta($feed_id, 'category_id', $_POST['category_id']);
        } 
         if (isset($_POST['feed_url']) && $_POST['feed_url'] != '') {            
            update_post_meta($feed_id, 'feed_url', $_POST['feed_url']);
        } 
    }
}
```

i want use custom filter based on category id in list page. please help me. How i can do this.
[image]

My category filter image[image]

Comment: Do you want to filter the posts by Category ?

Comment: Category filter is already available in wordpress post page. So what do you want extra there ?

Comment: No in my custom post_meta there is one custom column category_id so i want to filter list by category_id.

Comment: I have attached image also you can see.

Comment: where does this category ID come from. How do you select the category when you add a news feed. Do you have custom taxonomy?

Comment: i am adding category_id by custom_meta_box and saving into database.

Comment: can you add that custom meta box code as well

Comment: did my answer work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add a new custom category filter you need to hook to the `restrict_manage_posts` filter.

Add this in your themes `functions.php` file.

```
//filter to add custom category filter and modify request
add_filter( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'custom_category_id_filter'  );
add_filter( 'request', 'custom_category_id_request' );


function custom_category_id_request( $request ) {

    global $post_type;

    //return if we are not in wp-admin or the post type is not news_feed
    if ( !is_admin() || $post_type != 'news_feed')
        return $request;

    //check if meta value filter is called. if then set request params
    if ( isset( $_GET['mv'] ) and !empty( $_GET['mv'] )) {
        $request['meta_key']   = 'category_id';
        $request['meta_value'] = $_GET['mv'];
    }

    return $request;

}

function custom_category_id_filter( ) {

    global $wpdb, $post_type;

    //add this if we are in the specified post type
    if ( is_admin() && $post_type == 'news_feed') {

        $mvs = $wpdb->get_col( " SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'category_id' ORDER BY meta_value ASC " );

        ?>
        <select name="mv">
            <option value=""><?php _e( 'Show Posts from all Category ID', 'posts_meta_search' ); ?></option>
            <?php 
                if (!empty ($mvs)) { 
                    foreach ( $mvs as $mv ) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $mv ); ?>" <?php selected( $_GET['mv'], $mv ); ?>><?php echo esc_attr( $mv ); ?></option>
                <?php } 
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        <?php
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Since the meta_value column is varchar field you need to `cast` it as integer to sort it as 1,2,3 ...

Change your query in `custom_category_id_filter` as  follows:

```
$mvs = $wpdb->get_col( " SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'category_id' ORDER BY CAST( meta_value AS SIGNED INTEGER ) ASC  " );
```

Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: Hi @Sabari ! Now filter option is showing but on select of any category_id from drop-down it is not performing any action.

Comment: Its working fine @sabari ! i have added onChange="form.submit();"  :) thanx alot.Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: ! How i can make 'Show Posts from all Category ID' in "Asc" order.

Comment: @hina it is in ASC order. It will show 1,2,3. is that not working ?

Comment: No it is not coming in "Asc" order.

Comment: @hina how is your data now coming ??

Comment: @hina sorry there was a small issue in the query. I have updated that please check

Comment: I checked and its working fine for me. So how is your select box displaying the results. Can you post a screenshot

Comment: I have added image you can check now.

Comment: Seems that you need to order the wordpress default filter by alpahbetical order. I think by default wordpress dropdown categories filter is sorting in alphabetical order. which version of wordpress you are using?

Comment: Hi i am using Version 3.7.1

Comment: Hi can you check with function extra_tablenav in wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php. In that $dropdown_options orderby should be name. Can you check that ?

Comment: Hi @Sabari what i need to do if i want one filter in default user listing page of wordpress and if my meta_value is saving in wp_usermeta table.